# Use forward slash as a key command in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, key-binding

In tmux, is it possible to bind forward slash to a command?  The command I want to create is below:

```
bind-key -nr C-M-/ kill-window \; next-window
```

This config errors with: `/home/joe/.tmux.conf:42: unknown key: C-M-/`

The command works if I use a letter instead of a forward slash.  I want to use forward slash to mirror my emacs config.

Update:
Doesn't look like it's possible. According to the man page, only certain keys are white-listed.  The relevant section from the man page:

> **Key Bindings**
>
> tmux allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a
>   prefix key. When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for
>   example ‘A’ to ‘Z’). Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and
>   Alt (meta) with ‘M-’. In addition, the following special key names are
>   accepted: Up, Down, Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End,
>   Enter, Escape, F1 to F20, Home, IC (Insert), NPage (Page Up), PPage
>   (Page Down), Space, and Tab. Note that to bind the ‘"’ or ‘’’ keys,
>   quotation marks are necessary, for example:

Comment: `C-\ ` works for me (though I'm also having trouble with `C-/`), and its not mentioned in the "special key names" list --- I think that is just for keys that can't be typed as themselves (i.e., non-printing keys), or other special cases.  I don't think that means they're a "white list".

Answer (score 1):

As the update to the question states, I don't believe the specifically requested key binding is possible (without remapping your `/` key). However, to answer the more general question: just as how `C-[` and `Esc` are generally synonymous, so too are `C-_` and `C-/`, so you can at least bind `C-_` if you wish to use `C-/`.

E.g: `bind-key -nr C-_ kill-window \; next-window`

Answer (score -1):

In `.tmux.conf`, use: 
`set-option -g prefix 'C-\'`

Comment: That's a back slash.  The OP was asking about forward slash, which may be a different case.  Back slash (`C-\`) works for me, too.